# getStaticProps returning empthy object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

on IndexPage i am calling an api using getStaticProps. when i console.log this on frontend i get an empty object on the browser.

iam using **NextJS**

```
   const IndexPage = (props) => {
     console.log(props)
    return(
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
    }
    

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not play around with it, but I'm almost sure that if you view console output of you console where you started nextjs app you will see results there, take a look please. Here is explanation from documentation:

> If you export an async function called getStaticProps from a page, Next.js **will pre-render this page at build time** using the props returned by getStaticProps.

The key part here will pre-render at build time. So `getStaticProps` will be called on the server side during server side rendering.

Comment: yes, it does log on the terminal
but i want to show the data in the frontend

Comment: No problem, I assume you don't want just console.log it on front end side, in that case just wrap it into html you need. Nextjs will render everything on the server side and return back already rendered posts. Just try return this from your `InpdexPage`:  `return props.posts.map(post => <h2>{post.title}</h2>)`